# Argumental variable can't be accessed inside class initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

I wish to have a font management system of sorts, in which all of the usable fonts are in one single file that can be accessed by others instead of having to rewrite all the fonts for every TextStyle in the entire project. Here is such file:

```
class MyFonts {
  final Color surfaceColor;
  MyFonts(this.surfaceColor);

  static List<TextStyle> _fonts = [
  // style1Header
  TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Work Sans',
      fontSize: 37.sp,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: surfaceColor,
      letterSpacing: 0.25.sp
  ),
  ... // many other fonts
```

Since this isn't a stateful widget, I have to send through the initializer the colour of the context of the page it is being called from using the line `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceFf`.

The issue is that `color: surfaceColor` throws an error:

```
The instance member 'surfaceColor' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.
```

Is it wrong of me to send the theme of the surface as an argument? Is there another way to get the context of the app so that I don't have to send it as an argument? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color in the static style declaration doesn't make sense. The fonts should be able to have different colors, thus every font needs its own variable. This is what you already did.
Delete the line from the static style and apply the color for every font individually using [copyWith](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/copyWith.html):

```
style: _fonts.copyWith(color: surfaceColor)
```

I don't have the rest of your code, but this should be where you used `_fonts` before.

Comment: The only other part of the file is a simple getter: `static TextStyle getFont(int index) => _fonts[index - 1];`. So in the rest of the project, if theres a text that needs a certain style, then I just do `style: MyFonts.getFont(13)` or something like that. I should do then something like `style: MyFonts._fonts.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceFf)`??

Comment: Yes, but the direct version is slightly ugly. better change the getFont method instead: `static TextStyle getFont(int index, BuildContext context) => _fonts[index - 1].copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceFf;`

Comment: Thanks you for the answer to my problem! 
What I ended up with is that, inside the font manager file, I added a getter like this: 
`static TextStyle getFont(int index, [Color? colour]) => _fonts[index - 1].copyWith(color: colour);` 
This way, whenever I wish to get one font out of the list, I also have a choice to give it a colour or not like this: 
`style: MyFonts.getFont(10, Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceFf)` 
or simply: 
`style: MyFonts.getFont(10)`